# How to resolve 'Null Pointer Exception'

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, google-maps-api-2

I'm new to Android. I'm creating an application in which I have to use a map in my two activities. My application is running good but when I tap on my 'TagYourself' activity (one of the map activities) my application crashes. Log cat shows the null pointer exception on **line 46** which is `this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_tag_yourself);`. Log cat is also showing.
`android.view.InflateException` on Binary XML file line # 17 which is the fragment for map.

I couldn't understand why it is giving such exceptions. Please help me. 
Here is my log cat for the acitivity.

```
04-06 23:20:02.851: I/InputMethodManager(31122): handleMessage: MSG_SET_ACTIVE false, was true
04-06 23:20:02.867: I/InputMethodManager(31122): handleMessage: MSG_UNBIND 985
04-06 23:20:02.911: D/OpenGLRenderer(31122): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-06 23:20:03.276: D/OpenGLRenderer(31122): Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-06 23:20:08.341: V/PhoneWindow(31122): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0
04-06 23:20:08.386: V/InputMethodManager(31122): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=32 first=true flags=#1810100
04-06 23:20:08.386: V/InputMethodManager(31122): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41394140 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,854} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@412aebc0 controlFlags=#104
04-06 23:20:08.390: V/InputMethodManager(31122): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@412635d8 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #989}
04-06 23:20:08.420: I/InputMethodManager(31122): handleMessage: MSG_SET_ACTIVE true, was false
04-06 23:20:08.427: I/SurfaceTextureClient(31122): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52cb22e8) fps:0.15, dur:6849.47, max:6849.47, min:6849.47
04-06 23:20:08.427: I/SurfaceTextureClient(31122): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x52cb22e8, api:1, last queue time elapsed:6849.47
04-06 23:20:09.363: V/Provider/Settings(31122): invalidate [system]: current 182 != cached 0
04-06 23:20:09.367: D/ActivityThread(31122): installProvider: context=android.app.ContextImpl@41393588holder=android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@41271e08noisy=truenoReleaseNeeded=truestable=true
04-06 23:20:09.368: V/Provider/Settings(31122): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
04-06 23:20:09.393: D/mylog(31122): Wifi State true
04-06 23:20:09.514: I/SurfaceTextureClient(31122): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52cb22e8) fps:1.84, dur:1087.15, max:843.11, min:244.04
04-06 23:20:09.562: D/AndroidRuntime(31122): Shutting down VM
04-06 23:20:09.562: W/dalvikvm(31122): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cab9a8)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jamaat_times/com.example.jamaattiming.TagYourself}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class fragment
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at com.example.jamaattiming.TagYourself.onCreate(TagYourself.java:46)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    ... 11 more
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:436)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:255)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
04-06 23:20:09.584: E/AndroidRuntime(31122):    ... 21 more
```

here is xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#808080"
    tools:context=".TagYourself" 
    android:id="@+id/activity_tag_yourself">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_distance_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is Java Code for TagYourself Class:

```
    public class TagYourself extends FragmentActivity
{
    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    TextView tvDistanceDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_tag_yourself);

        this.tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);
        // Initializing
        this.markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();


        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        this.map = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        this.map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        this.map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point)
            {
                // Already two locations
                if (TagYourself.this.markerPoints.size() > 1)
                {
                    TagYourself.this.markerPoints.clear();
                    TagYourself.this.map.clear();
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                TagYourself.this.markerPoints.add(point);

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                /**
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                 */
                if (TagYourself.this.markerPoints.size() == 1)
                {
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                } else if (TagYourself.this.markerPoints.size() == 2)
                {
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }

                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                TagYourself.this.map.addMarker(options);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if (TagYourself.this.markerPoints.size() >= 2)
                {
                    LatLng origin = TagYourself.this.markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = TagYourself.this.markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = TagYourself.this.getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest)
    {
        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException
    {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally
        {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
```

I've uses the following permissions:

```
 <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="11"
  android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.jamaat_times.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

P.S: There is no problem in my key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null

You are missing `android:name` attribute for the fragment

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time" 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer sir. My Problem Has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your xml

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_contet" 
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_distance_time"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```